# Angular 2 : Input error

Tags: angular

I'm working on a project in which a search feature has been implemented. The input element looks like this :

```
<input #input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" id="nav-input" (ngModelChange)="onquery($event)"
           [(ngModel)]="searchdata.query" autocomplete="off" (keypress)="onEnter($event)">

onEnter(event: any) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
      this.displayStatus = 'hidebox';
      event.target.blur();
      this.submit();
    }

submit() {
    if (this.searchdata.query.toString().length !== 0) {
      if (!this.router.url.toString().includes('/search')) {
        this.router.navigate(['/search'], {queryParams: this.searchdata});
      }
```

On typing a query and hitting enter key, it shows error in console:

```
Form submission canceled because the form is not connected
```

I'm not able to figure out, how to solve this issue. It will be great if someone can help me out. :)

Comment: I suppose that when you press `enter` you are triggering the form submit. Have you checked that?

Comment: You are not giving us enough code. Please provide the whole form and whole `submit` method

Comment: please update the code with the whole `<form>` not just the `<input>`

Comment: @crash I have not used `<form>` element, just `<input>` element inside div tag.

Comment: @FredrikLundin I have not used `form` element. Just `input` inside div tag. And `submit()` is with whole code. :)

Comment: have a look at my answer. Also, if you are familiar with `Observables` I can suggest a better pattern for what you want to achieve. Why are you updating `searchdata.query` on each keystroke if you use it only after pressing the `enter` button?

Comment: @crash to have a feature like instant search just like Google. :p that's why `searchdata.query` is being updated on each keystroke. I have provided both options like instant search on and off.

Comment: so there's some sort of variable controlling whether to use instant search or search on enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `event.preventDefault()` in the `onEnter` function should solve the problem since it is maybe trying to send a non-existing form.

Answer (score 0):

change the name of function onEnter() from your template and your component. use any other name not this.

Comment: i think there might be any onEnter events in html or js. not sure about this.